# Align a child Left in Parent ( relative layout) but to the half of the visible screen

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment

I have many child in a relative layout and I want them some of them to `Align Left` and some of them `align right` **But** align left should take half of the screen and align right should take remaining half. How could I do that?

Size of the child is not the same I want something like this:

[image: The screenshot of what I want]

I have successfully align child to left and right but problem is with the weight both should take half of screen. If I use 2 layouts with same weight then `layout_below` I can't use, let say I want textview People below the status as in image attached. Status has a wide description that is aligned end of the layout.

Code of relative layout XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.inzimam.tariq.bookmyumrah.BookingHistoryList"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_booking_history_list">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Booking Number:"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="990NMI"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Agent Name:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1_left"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Afaq International"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv1_left"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Package Name:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv2_left"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="14 Nights Budget Package"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv2_left"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv4_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Order Date:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv3_left"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="05 May 2016"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv3_left"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv5_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Status:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv4_left"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Preregistered. Waiting for confir-mation. Our representative will
call you soon to verify the order.
For any assistance please contact
us at booking@bookmyumrah.pk
Or call us at 0321-1111-268
"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv4_left"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you use LinearLayout with horizantal orientaion and weights?

Comment: Sound like "do my homework"...first of all post your efforts for this.

Comment: @Raghavendra a single Linear layout ? or 2

Comment: @InzimamTariq is that data dynamic or its always same?

Comment: Post the code that you tried so far.

Comment: you can use linear layout instead of  RelativeLayout or also try Table layout for that.